# Copying Qt dlls in post build event using windeployqt is not working

Tags: c++, qt

on my system Qt is located in `C:\Libraries\Qt\5.12.6\VS2015\shared\x64` (compiled from sources).
I am using this Qt version in Visual Studio with the Qt Add-In without any problems.

Now I want to automatically copy the required Qt dlls for my applicaton with "windeployqt".

I added the following post build event:

```
cd "$(QTDIR)\bin\" 
windeployqt "$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)"
```

Which results in:

```
cd "C:\Libraries\Qt\5.12.6\VS2015\shared\x64\bin\" 
windeployqt "C:\PathToSoftware\TestSoftware.exe"
```

Nevertheless, I get the following error:

> EXEC : warning : Unable to read
> C:\Qt\5.12.6\install\win32-msvc2015\x64\mkspecs\qconfig.pri: The
> system cannot find the path specified. Unable to find dependent
> libraries of C:\Qt\5.12.6\install\win32-msvc2015\x64\bin\Qt5Core.dll
> :Cannot open
> 'C:/Qt/5.12.6/install/win32-msvc2015/x64/bin/Qt5Core.dll': The system
> cannot find the path specified.

The same problem arises if I run "windeployqt" in the command prompt:

```
C:\Libraries\Qt\5.12.6\VS2015\shared\x64\bin\windeployqt "C:\PathToSoftware\TestSoftware.exe"
```

Any ideas how to fix that problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the documentation says:  windeployqt needs to be run within the build environment in order to function correctly. When using Qt Installer, the script QTDIR/bin/qtenv2.bat should be used to set it up.

So try to execute the script **QTDIR/bin/qtenv2.bat** before calling windeployqt.